# How can I get a list of (lat, lon) pairs for a way in a single call to the OSM API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Given the ID of a Way in OSM, I'd like to get a list of (lat, lon) pairs.

If I request the way via the standard API, I get a list of Node IDs:

```
$ curl 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/158602261'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" ...>
 <way id="158602261" visible="true" ...>
  <nd ref="295505187"/>
  <nd ref="1736599935"/>
  <nd ref="295505112"/>
  ...
</osm>
```

I can then do follow-up queries for each of these nodes:

```
$ curl 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/295505187'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" ...>
  <node id="295505187" visible="true" ... lat="37.7702484" lon="-122.5107188"/>
</osm>
```

But this will require many API requests, one per node in the path.

Is it possible to get the list of lat/lons using fewer API calls? Just one call would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append */full* to the URL, e.g. http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/158602261/full.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this can be done with the plain-old OSM API, but it can be done using the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Streets_and_other_ways)'s recurse down statement:

```
$ curl 'http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=%5Bout:json%5D;(way(158602261);%3E;);out;'
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API",
  ...
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 30677708,
  "lat": 37.7712040,
  "lon": -122.5108280
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 30677709,
  "lat": 37.7730278,
  "lon": -122.4715596
},
...
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 158602261,
  "nodes": [
    295505187,
    1736599935,
    295505112,
    295505186,
    ...
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly asked for a list of lat/lon pairs for a single way id, you could use the Overpass API CSV output mode.

```
[out:csv(::lat,::lon;false)];
way(158602261);>;out;
```

(Headerline is suppressed by "false")

Result:

```
37.7712040  -122.5108280
37.7730278  -122.4715596
37.7733457  -122.4652858
37.7746245  -122.4547306
37.7664503  -122.4531098
...
```

Overpass Turbo Link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6NG